# Get js localstorage items case insensitive

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

After saving items in javascript local storage I want to retrieve them case insensitive based on the key saved in the localstorage.

For example if I have '**Test**' as a key in local storage localstorage.getItem('**test**'); doesn't return the value of '**Test**' cause it is case sensitive. I want to be able to get the item regardless.

Is there a way to do this without looping thourgh the local storage and using `toLowerCase()` function for each key I find as in the code below:

```
    for (var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++){
    if( localStorage.key(i).toLowerCase()==searchedKey.toLowerCase() ){
    matchingKey =true;
    break;
    }        }
```

Comment: What do you do when there're both `Test` and `test`?..

Comment: Do .toLowerCase() on writting into localstorage.

Comment: I am permitting the existence of test and Test as I am using the key like the same concept of a file name, so when you save Test and try to save a new file name test it will overwrite the old one and warn you that you already have it. @nicael

Comment: I was using toLowerCase() when writting into localstorage but I want the user to see how he exactly saved while searching in a list I provide. @Jonas

Comment: localStorage.getItem(key) || localStorage.getItem(key.toLowerCase())

Comment: That doesn't solve it, lets say you saved Test as key and the user typed test.  localStorage.getItem('test') II localStorage.getItem('test'.toLowerCase()) won't result in success to find the Key Test.

Comment: @NatalieBoudakian If `Test` and `test` are "the same", you probably should be normalizing them at storage time. If you want to keep the original capitalization available, make it part of the value. If `Test` and `test` are different, what would you expect when doing case-insensitive lookup - a collection of matches? I don't think the API exposes the option, so I think the loop is your best bet. Or course, you could loop once during initialization and then maintain a lookup yourself as an optimization if performance is your concern.

Comment: Storing the original value in the local storage key is sensible, and normalising on case. That stops you from needing to do N lookups and turns it into an O(1) process.

Comment: Create a wrapper to wrap your localStorage access, where you make sure that the keys for setting and getting the values are always lowerCased or upperCased

Answer (score 0):

`localStorage` is a Dictionary. It stores Key/Value pairs. Both Key and Value are `string`.

As Dictionary keys must be unique, values as `Test` and `test` are not the same, and therefore must be saved into Dictionary as 2 separate entries.

Also, `localStorage` has no functionality to get all added Keys or Values, unlike C# or Java. Don't know exact reason for this functionality being missed. It can be due to security, so that rogue JavaScript has no ability to interrogate the storage, or just to keep it simple.

The only way to get value by case insensitive Key, is to store them case insensitive.

You can use either `toUpper` or `toLower` on Key before adding it to `localStorage`. However, Microsoft says converting to upper case is safest: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/visualstudio/code-quality/ca1308-normalize-strings-to-uppercase?view=vs-2015